# Custom Route Name Angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Currently, my route is

```
 Routes = [
   {
path: '',
component: MainLayoutComponent,
children: [ 
  { path: 'activity', component: ActivityListComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'userReport', component: ReportsComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
]
}]
```

I want to change the URL **http://localhost:1234/userReport**     to **http://localhost:1234/ReportSection**

I have done to do the same

```
 {path: "userReport", component: ReportsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],data: { routeName: "ReportSection" }}
```

But it didn't work.

Then I tried this

```
{path: "ReportSection", component: ReportsComponent,pathMatch: 'full', canActivate:   
[AuthGuard] }
```

And this gives me an error **Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'userReport'**

Is there any other way to change the URL name?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just change the path?..

Comment: if I change the path to e.g. userReport1 then it gives me an error that cannot match any route . URL Segment  userReport

Comment: I think you need to clarify the problem more, because currently it makes no sense.

Comment: Have you imported routes?? 

import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

Comment: @Vishal_VE than how can applications will work without importing them. These routes are imported by default. You don't need to import them. Angular does it for you.

Comment: I know and I am just clearing that it should be there. The custom URL will be changing from the path. For more, you need to show your routing module file.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the path like this :

```
{ path: 'ReportSection', component: ReportsComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
```